# autocomplete is not a function Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are tons of discussions about this topic, but I don't see an answer that fits this particular situation. In a Rails 4 application, I am trying to use "autocomplete" from JQuery UI, like this:

```
$(function() {

$(".donor_name").autocomplete({
source: '/donors/?format=json'
  });
});
```

The Javascript console error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

which seems to be saying, it isn't finding JQuery UI.

Gemfile:
     group :assets do
       gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
     end
     gem 'jquery-rails'

and then in app/assets/javascripts/application.js,

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

(I tried require jquery-ui but that wasn't recognized)

versions:
jquery-rails 4.0.4
jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5

Perhaps someone has seen this before?

UPDATE. @MarsAtomic, I am using the gems, and to the other person, I did follow the directions in that gem documentation. My installation somehow doesn't find "jquery-ui". I was hoping someone had seen this problem before.

Comment: If you're trying to use functionality from the JQuery UI library, but you don't provide it as an asset, then you can't really expect it to work, can you? Are you using the jquery-ui-rails gem or are you just trying to drop a copy of JQuery UI into your app/assets/scripts directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need jQuery ui installed. The rails gem and instructions are here: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails